# Calling one Perl program from another

Tags: perl

I have two Perl files and I want to call one file from another with arguments

#### First file `a.pl`

```
$OUTFILE  = "C://programs/perls/$ARGV[0]";
# this should be some out file created inside work like C://programs/perls/abc.log
```

#### Second File `abc.pl`

```
require "a.pl" "abc.log";

# $OUTFILE is a variable inside a.pl and want to append current file's name as log.
```

I want it to create an output file with the name of log as that of current file.

One more constraint I have is to use `$OUTFILE` in both `a.pl` and `abc.pl`.

If there is any better approach please suggest.

Answer (score 7):

The `require` keyword only takes one argument. That's either a file name or a package name. Your line

> ```
> require "a.pl" "abc.log";
> ```

is wrong. It gives a syntax error along the lines of *String found where operator expected*.

You can require one `.pl` file from another `.pl`, but that is very old-fashioned, badly written Perl code.

If neither file defines a package then the code is implicitly placed in the `main` package. You can [declare a package variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html) in the outside file and use it in the one that is required.

In `abc.pl`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# declare a package variable
our $OUTFILE  = "C://programs/perls/filename";

# load and execute the other program
require 'a.pl';
```

And in `a.pl`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# do something with $OUTFILE, like use it to open a file handle
print $OUTFILE;
```

If you run this, it will print

```
C://programs/perls/filename
```

Comment: How about setting filename as environment variable? Are there any loose ends of that?

Comment: @Pyjava no, that would work too. `%ENV` is global (see discussion on the other answer) and will be accessible from the other code. When you `require` a file without a package it gets executed in the spot. The scope is different but the package stays the same. So there really is no difference in terms of the outcome.

Comment: @Pyjava please take a moment to take the [tour] and read [ask] to learn what to do when someone answers your question and solves the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should convert your perl file you want to call to a perl module:

Hello.pm

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package Hello;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub printHello { 
    print "Hello $_[0]\n" 
}
1;
```

Then you can call it:
test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# you have to put the current directory to the module search path
use lib (".");
use Hello;

Hello::printHello("a");
```

I tested it in git bash on windows, maybe you have to do some modifications in your environment.

In this way you can pass as many arguments as you would like to, and you don't have to look for the variables you are using and maybe not initialized (this is a less safe approach I think, e.g. sometimes you will delete something you did't really want) somewhere in the file you want to call. The disadvantage is that you need to learn a bit about perl modules but I think it definitely worths.

A second approach could be to use the exec/system call (you can pass arguments in this way too; if forking a child process is acceptable), but that is an another story.

Comment: The question is asking about sharing a variable between two files without a package. While I would prefer the approach of using modules that you are suggesting, I think that's not really what the OP wants (or needs, homework?) to do. Please also note that [`.` was removed from `@INC` only in Perl 5.26](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2017/01/v5-26-removes-dot-from-inc/), so the `use lib` _might not_ be necessary. I'd also like to point out that the tutorialspoint page you link to is horribly outdated and suggests bad style Perl code.

Comment: (I haven't voted on your answer, because I think it's well-written and a good suggestion, but not a direct answer. If you flesh it out some more, add `use strict` and `use warnings` and explain _why_ this is a good idea, you'll get my upvote :)

Comment: It was never written that "without a package". I wrote . because I don't like to use hardcoded paths in code and  I did not want to use another Perl module to figure out the current path. I did not want to suggest a module that needs to be installed in order to be able to use it, I assumed that the author has less experience with modules. This version is just an easy and fast solution, and IMHO it is a better approach than defining a global variable in the first file and using the require to call the others, as you suggested.

Comment: Your use a package in a `.pm` file is what is commonly referred to as a _module_ in Perl. That doesn't have to do a lot or come from CPAN. As I said, it's totally fine and a good solution, but I believe it needs more explanation in the answer on _why_ it is a better solution than moving a variable through. The variable I used in my answer is not _global_ though. It's a package variable in the `main::` package. There is a difference. It's not possible to define your own _global_ variables in Perl, but some variables like `$a` or `@ARGV` are in fact global.

Comment: I agree with your assessment that OP is less experienced with using modules. Hence I inferred _without a package_ from the lack of `package` keywords and the use of `.pl` files instead of a `.pm` file in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this another way. Have the program take the name of the log file as a command-line parameter:

```
% perl a.pl name-of-log-file
```

Inside *a.pl*, open that file to append to it then output whatever you like. Now you can run it from many other sorts of places besides another Perl program.

```
# a.pl
my $log_file = $ARGV[0] // 'default_log_name';
open my $fh, '>>:utf8', $log_file or die ...;
print { $fh } $stuff_to_output;
```

But, you could also call if from another Perl program. The `$^X` is the path to the currently running *perl* and this uses `system` in the slightly-safer list form:

```
system $^X, 'a.pl', $name_of_log_file
```

How you get something into `$name_of_log_file` is up to you. In your example you already knew the value in your first program.